# Do I have to get "Frozen Asset" before the end of the game?

Tags: achievements, infamous-2

Looking over the description for the [Frozen Asset](http://www.ign.com/wikis/infamous-2/Frozen_Asset) trophy I see there should be 4 side missions. On my Good playthrough I helped the Ice Soldier and...none of the other missions showed up.

I haven't completed the rest of the non-Ice Soldier side missions, but I've completed the game and am on Chapter 40: Aftermath. I've never done an evil side mission in this playthrough, yet I don't see any of the other three Blue side missions for this quest and I haven't gotten the trophy.

Do I have to get this achievement before the end of the game or are there some other conditions at work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it wasn't on my map before, but today when I played I did in fact find the Stay Frosty,Big Chill and Mercy Kill missions (in order) on my map and was able to play them, so you *can* play them after the end of the game, though playing certain Evil sidemissions on the second island (Floodtown and Gas Works) *will* lock out the missions forever (as my Evil playthrough confirms).

Answer (score -2):

Yes you do. You can pick either frozen asset or the shapeshifter girls powers. I would prefer frozen.